# Ember : addObject/ pushObject is not a function

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I recently moved from ember 1.x to 2.6. I am not able to use addObject/pushObject like i used to.

```
Ember      : 2.6.2
jQuery     : 2.2.4

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    test: ['sibi', 'john'],

    init: function() {
        this.get('test').pushObject('sebastian');
    }
});
```

This throws an error like pushObject is not a function. What is the workaround? Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that "[]" does not initialize Ember compatible array anymore (prototype extensions). Probably you need to allow this behavior explicitly in your config file. By now try replacing `test:['sibi', 'john']` using Ember.Array: `test: Ember.A(['sibi', 'john'])`

Comment: As a random side note, it's generally bad practice to add an array reference to a class definition.  All instances of that class created will share the same reference to that array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extend prototypes option was false for some reason.
You can read more about disabling prototype extensions in the [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/).

```
EmberENV: {
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        Array: true
      }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: config file is `config/environment.js`

Answer (score 4):

Check your `package.json` against `ember-disable-prototype-extensions`.

If your project is an addon project it had beed added by ember-cli. And you should live with it. (Use `Ember.A` whenever you need an Ember array.)

If your project is an application project, just remove this addon.

Comment: That was not the case..Enabling the extend prototypes option was what worked for me.

Comment: Then why was it disabled? By default it had to be enabled.

Comment: I am not sure about that. My package.json did not have the "ember-disable-prototype-extensions" entry.

Comment: Interesting. [By default, Ember.js will extend the prototypes of native JavaScript objects](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/). Maybe one of your addons you used is disabling it.