# pushobject is not a function emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I've got an odd issue with ember js, when i push an object to a model. Here is my code:

```
// Environment.js
  EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
    // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
    Date: true,
    Array: true,
  }
```

Route.js

```
 model () {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    newCollection: this.get('store').createRecord('collection'),
    book1: this.get('store').createRecord('book'),
    book2: this.get('store').createRecord('book')
  })
}
```

Controller

```
actions:{
  addCollection(model) {
    model.newCollection.pushObject(model.book1);
    model.newCollection.pushObject(model.book2);
  },
}
```

Now I'm not sure what the issue, but I'm trying to push the book model into the collection, however, I get an issue with this as the console log suggests that pushObject is not a function. I've updated my Environment.js as other questions have suggested, however this still is an issue.

Collection Model

```
// collection Model
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.attr('string'),
    books: DS.hasMany('book', { async: true })
});
```

The book model

```
//book Model
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    collection: DS.belongsTo('collection', {async: true})
});
```

Comment: please show your models

Comment: @Lux the models have been added to the question

Comment: duplicate [Ember : addObject/ pushObject is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714527/ember-addobject-pushobject-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that `newCollection` is a collection record.
So you should do:

```
model.newCollection.get('books').pushObject(model.book1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. You're pushing to the actual model instead of the `books` `hasMany` relationship:

```
actions: {
  addCollection(model) {
    model.newCollection.get('books').pushObject(model.book1);
    model.newCollection.get('books').pushObject(model.book2);
  },
}
```

Comment: Actually no. `model` is *not* an ember Object. He's returning `return Ember.RSVP.hash({...})`.

Comment: Addressed the comment.